# How to sum up ranges with Python depending on a state?

Tags: python, range

I'm having a hard time to find the right terms for what I want to do, which is why my question (title) is a little inaccurate for the moment (will edit once better understood).

One example: I have time ranges on a per day basis:

```
[ { "begin": "02:05", "end": "07:05" },
  { "begin": "14:05", "end": "17:05" } ]
```

During these times a resource is available (in my case cheaper electricity).

Then there is an object which wants to use this resource as a priority during these time ranges. (in my case, charging a huge battery). There is also a start-time and an ideal end-time.

The same problem exists with other ranges using other units. For example, the huge battery has different charging efficiencies depending on its state-of-charge. So the charging speed is different.

```
[ { "begin": 0,    "end": 0.1, "eff": 0.82 },
  { "begin": 0.11, "end": 0.8, "eff": 0.98 },
  { "begin": 0.81, "end": 1,   "eff": 0.82 } ]
```

This table is needed to calculate the total time it will take to charge to selected state using the available power, the capacity of the battery and the target-state-of-charge.

---

What the correct name for this kind of problem? What are the right terms?

My current implementation is looping over these ranges and a bunch of if's and else's handle the corner-cases. It works, but I'm not very proud of the code.

Is there any library/tool in Python which could help me simplify my ugly loops?

Is there a python library which provides a mechanism to calculate

Comment: can you maybe provide an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: You mentioned you already have a working piece of code. Can you share it so others can have a better idea about your specific problem and what you are trying to do?

Comment: My guess is, this kind of problem is related to Dynamic Programming. My understanding of your problem is, you have a device that you need to charge from X% to Y%. The time of charging is estimated by the efficiency of the device's charging rate, so you need to first calculate the charging time. Then the 2nd problem is with that charging time, which time of the date that you should start charging your device.

Comment: @sekky my code is as ugly as you can imagine. My problem is generic one I'm sure and the given examples are nothing more than that. Don't want to limit your imagination.

Comment: @htr.dev that's the concrete example, I'm looking for the generic solution based on the data-structures as I showed above. I'm that there is.

Comment: "Is there a python library which provides a mechanism to calculate" what? Something is missing here.

Comment: You're missing a description of the expected output, even if the problem is to be thought of as a gereric one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure what exactly your expected output would be, but from htr.dev's comment I think what you want to aim for is some kind of weighted sum of a matrix.

That might require playing around with a matrix and vector a bit, but it might lead you to code that is way more clean, simple, and quite a bit faster.

As far as I know libraries like numpy offer functionality for such calculations.
Have a look at this question: [Numpy Array summing with weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679523/numpy-array-summing-with-weights)